# Web Form ReportViewerControl Customization

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, reportviewer

I would like to customize asp.net web form reportviewer control. Particularly, I would like to override the default value in reportviewer control. How could this be done? I would like to have something like this for example.

I am not looking for something like this but the default asyncrendering method in reportviewer is **public bool AsyncRendering** and not **public virtual bool AsyncRendering**

```
<crv:ReportViewer runat="server" AsyncRendering="false" />
```

Instead, I am looking for something like this.

```
public class CustomReportViewer : ReportViewerControl
{
   public override bool AsyncRendering
   {
       if(AsyncRendering.HasNoValue)
       {
          return false;
       }
       else
       {
          return true;
       }
   }
}

<crv:CustomReportViewer runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as you cannot override the property because it is not virtual, what you can do it create a CustomReportViewer like you did:

```
public class CustomReportViewer : Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer
{
   //You can create a customreportviewer like you did 
}
```

But then, the trick here would be to create your own composite control with this CustomReportViewer inside.

```
[ToolboxData("<{0}:MyReportViewerControl runat=server></{0}:MyReportViewerControl>")]
public class MyReportViewerControl : CompositeControl, IPostBackEventHandler, IPostBackDataHandler
{
     //additional code
     protected override void CreateChildControls()
     {
         //Here add you customized reportviewer
         var rv = new CustomReportViewer();
         rv.AsyncRendering = false;
     }
     //additional code
}
```

Comment: Hi based on your code I have done some research on toolbox data. Why asynrendering must in override CreateChildControls instead of like this?? `[ToolboxData("<{0}:MyReportViewerControl runat='server' AsyncRendering='false'></{0}:MyReportViewerControl>")]public class MyReportViewControl: ReportViewerControl {}`

Comment: Because `MyReportViewerControl` is your own Custom control, the actual reportviewer control is something you are creating privately inside your control and you are not exposing any properties of this in your MyReportViewerControl. So you do not have `AsyncRendering` property in `MyReportViewerControl`

Comment: @vincentsty forgot to add that `MyReportViewerControl` is based on `CompositeControl` not `ReportViewerControl` which makes it a custom server control